# How do I change university on academia.edu?

Tags: affiliation

I mostly avoid academia.edu and research.gate, but last I knew, a lot of Social Sciences and Humanities (SSH) people spend time there, and I just had an SSH publication come out, so I'm updating both sites. I also got a new job three years ago at a different university than the one academia.edu knows. I was able to update my email on academia.edu, but my URL is hardcoded to my former (British) university. I don't care enough to delete & rebuild my account, but if there's a simple fix, can someone let me know?

Surprised this question isn't already here, but I can't find a duplicate...

Comment: The question was not closed due it being unclear, but rather because this concerncs the inner workings of another website. For the same reason a lot of google scholar related questions get closed as of topic (see this meta post: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/should-we-make-google-scholar-questions-off-topic)

Comment: But this is a thing academics use and need to figure out. It's commercial but.

Answer (score 2):

The system edited my URL itself 30 minutes after I edited the email address or so; I did not need to do anything further besides the changes already made. In case anyone else is in a similar situation, it seems the answer is to just be patient and wait.

Comment: This answer has been downvoted and flagged as "not an answer" multiple times, but I cannot see any evidence for that. To hopefully prevent that happening again I've rewritten it slightly while maintaining the same message: the answer is "just wait, it'll update". Maybe that's not a particularly profound answer, but it's apparently the answer in this situation. Users of StackExchange may be familiar with this sort of thing, as a lot of stuff here (badges, automatic deletion) run on a maintenance schedule where it takes some time for things to update. Also https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @BryanKrause, self answers are uncommon enough here that it might be the reason. They are quite common on other sites, though.

Comment: @Buffy Maybe, but this is a circumstance where it absolutely makes sense.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that  you can't actively do something so it seems like it isn't an answer, though actually waiting is an action, people have trouble reasoning about it. If someone else has a better answer they should of course say?

Comment: Maybe also the question was viewed as self promoting because I gave TMI I've now edited it down to the essentials.